# declaring class variable c++

Tags: c++, yacc, lex

So I'm at a complete loss...

In my code I've got

```
void Parser(FILE* file)
{
    Parser par(file);
    par.Parse();
}
```

and I call it in my main function with
`Parser(file);`
and the header file I've got (which I included in the main file) looks like:

```
class Parser: public Lexer
{
public:
    Parser(FILE* file):Lexer(file);
    int Parse();
};
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
p02.cpp: In function 'void Parser(FILE*)':
p02.cpp:20: error: expected ';' before 'par'
p02.cpp:21: error: 'par' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [p02.o] Error 1
```

What I don't understand is why it is expecting a semicolon before par. Isn't that a legal declaration of a variable for that class?

Edit2: Changing my function name to not be Parser like the class name does not solve this problem. It does give me an *extra* error telling me that Parser is not declared in this scope, but I cannot see how that is when I've added the include file containing the Parser class right above the declaration for the function.

Edit: My Files
p02.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

#include "p02lex.h"
#include "y.tab.h"

using namespace std;

void Parser(FILE* file)
{
    Parser par(file);
    par.Parse();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char fileName[255];

    switch(argc)
    {
            case 1:
                    cout << "Enter the input file name. ";
                    cin >> fileName;
                    break;
            case 2:
                    strcpy(fileName, argv[1]);
                    break;
            default:
                    cout << "Too many arguments!\n";
                    exit(1);
    }

    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    Parser(file);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

p02lex.l:

```
#include "p02lex.h"

#define ID              257
...
#define PROGRAM         304

int TokenMgr(int t);
const char* getTokens(int tokenCode);

unsigned lineCount = 1, columnCount = 1;
%}

LETTER [a-z]|[A-Z]
DIGIT [0-9]

%%
// rules defined here, calling TokenMgr()
%%
int TokenMgr(int t)
{
/*      int tc = t;
    if (t == IDENTIFIER)
    {
            char s[1024];
            ToLower(s, yytext, strlen(yytext));
            tc = RW[s];
            if (tc == 0)
                    tc = t;
    }

    PrintToken(tfs, tc, line, col);
    col += yyleng; */ //JEG

    printf("Token:Code=%d Name=%10s line=%3u col=%3u Spelling=\"%s\"\n", t, getTokens(t), lineCount, columnCount, yytext);

    columnCount += yyleng;

    return /* tc */ 0; // JEG
}

Lexer::Lexer(FILE* file)
{
    yyin = file;
}

int Lexer::Scan(void)
{
    return yylex();
}

const char* getTokens(int tokenCode)
{
    switch(tokenCode)
    {
            case ID:
                    return "ID";
            ... // more cases, returning strings
            default:
                    return NULL;
    }
 }
```

p02lex.h:

```
#ifndef p02lex_h
#define p02lex_h 1
#endif

int yylex(void);

class Lexer
{
public:
    Lexer(FILE* file);

    int Scan(void);
};
```

p02par.h:

```
#ifndef p02par_h
#define p02par_h 1
#endif

using namespace std;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif

int yyparse(void);

class Parser: public Lexer
{
public:
    Parser(FILE* file):Lexer(file){}

    void Parse();

    // int Scan(void);
};
```

p02par.y:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "p02lex.h"
#include "p02par.h"

void yyerror(const char* m);
%}

%token PROGRAM
%token ID
%token SEMICOLON

%%
program:
    PROGRAM ID SEMICOLON
    { printf("Stuff happens!\n"); }

%%
void yyerror(const char* m)
{
    printf("%s\n", m);
}

/*Parser::Parser(FILE* file):Lexer(file)
{
}*/

int Parser::Parse()
{
    return yyparse();
}
```

p02make:

```
#LEX = flex
#YACC = yacc -d

CC = g++
OBJ = p02.o p02par.o p02lex.o

p02:    ${OBJ}
    $(CC) -o p02 ${OBJ} -ll -ly

y.tab.h p02par.cpp:     p02par.y
    yacc -d -v p02par.y
    mv y.tab.c p02par.cpp

p02lex.cpp:     p02lex.l
    lex p02lex.l
    mv lex.yy.c p02lex.cpp

p02par.o:       p02par.cpp p02par.h
    $(CC) -c -g p02par.cpp

p02.o:  p02.cpp p02lex.h p02par.h
    $(CC) -c -g p02.cpp

p02lex.o:       p02lex.cpp p02lex.h y.tab.h
    $(CC) -c -g p02lex.cpp
```

Comment: Don't give functions and classes the same identifier, it will only confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

that should be :

`Parser(File* file):Lexer(file) {}`

Wait I checked that code, rename the function: `void Parser(FILE *f)` to something else.

Comment: Updated my code to do that. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can only include an initializer list in a constructor *definition*, not a constructor declaration, so it must be followed by a function body (often empty), not a semicolon. There's also a bit of a problem with a name conflict:

```
void Parser(FILE* file) // here you've defined Parser as the name of a function
{
    Parser par(file); // but here you're trying to use it as the name of a class.
    par.Parse();
}
```

Edit: Here's a bit of code that compiles cleanly, at least with the compilers I have handy:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Lexer {
    FILE *infile;
public:
    Lexer(FILE *f) : infile(f) {}
};

class Parser : public Lexer {
public:
    Parser(FILE *f) : Lexer(f) {}
    void Parse() {}
};

void do_parse(FILE *file) {
    Parser p(file);
    p.Parse();
}
```

Comment: When I change `void Parser...` to `void myParser...` and then try to run it I'm given: `'Parser' was not declared in this scope` and then the original error message.

Comment: @James: I've added some code that compiles cleanly, as a guideline of what works.

Comment: I tried this out and it started messing up my lexer too much. I think I'm going to go ahead an add all the code from all my files into my original question. I warn you, however, its not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify `Parser` because the function has the same identifier as the class:

```
void Parser(FILE* file)
{
    class Parser par(file);
    par.Parse();
}
```

You could also rename the function.

You also need braces here:

```
Parser(FILE* file):Lexer(file) {}
```

Comment: Good catch on the naming conflict.  The better solution is of course to rename one.

Comment: Ok, so when I follow this it removes the errors I'm given and instead gives me `p02.cpp:20: error: variable 'Parser par' has initializer but incomplete type`

Comment: @James Is the file that contains the `Parser` class included before the function declaration? If not, do so.

Comment: Yes, I do `#include "y.tab.h"` about 4 lines above.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
void Parser(FILE* file)
```

to

```
Parser::Parser(FILE* file)
```

Constructors do not have a return type.

Comment: Removing the void from in front gives a new error:

`p02.cpp:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Parser' with no type`

Then the original error remains after that one.

Comment: It isn't a constructor, that would be `Parser::Parser`.

Comment: From the function prototype, it seemed like he was trying to write the constructor. But, you are right, I missed the scope resolution operator in my answer.